# set number of retries with HttpAsyncClients

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient

With the typical `HttpAsyncClients` example:

```
public class AsyncClientHttpExchange {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
        try {
            httpclient.start();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/get");
            Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(request, null);
            HttpResponse response = future.get();
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println("Shutting down");
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

What is the way to set the number of retries in case there is no response?. I can see 5.

With `httpClientBuilder` there is the `setRetryHandler` :

```
httpClientBuilder.setRetryHandler(new MyRequestRetryHandler(_maxRetryCount));
```

What is the way with `HttpAsyncClients`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HttpAsyncClient 4.x does not support automatic request re-execution. This feature is planned for HttpAsyncClient 5.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer @oleg

Comment: It's released already  https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/index.html